# Take a value in array1, a value in array2, see if the sum is equal to target value

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Question: You have two integer arrays, a and b, and an integer target value v. Determine whether there is a pair of numbers, where one number is taken from a and the other from b, that can be added together to get a sum of v.

Input:

```
sumOfTwo([1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30, 40], 42)
```

Output: `return true if a pair exists, else return false`

Please see my code below:

```
function sumOfTwo(a, b, v) {
            var correctArr = [];
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                    sum = a[i] + b[j];
                    if(sum === v){
                        console.log("bingo");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is I can not execute the return false part if I just change the else statement to return false.

Can anyone help to see any wrong with my code?

Comment: Put `return false` at the end of the function?

Comment: yes. adding a return false at the end can solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `return` statement at the end of the function to return a defined value.

---

By having sorted arrays, you could add a short circuit and omit further iterations if the sum is greater than the wanted sum.

```js
function sumOfTwo(a, b, v) {
    var correctArr = [],
        sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            sum = a[i] + b[j];
            if (sum === v) return true;
            if (sum > v) break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(sumOfTwo([1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30, 40], 42)); // true
console.log(sumOfTwo([1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30, 40], 25)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return `false` after the for loop. All the computations are done and you are sure the output will be `true` if there is a match.

```
function sumOfTwo(a, b, v) {
  var correctArr = [];
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
          sum = a[i] + b[j];
          if(sum === v){
              console.log("bingo");
              return true;
          }
      }
  }
  return false;
}
```